# Converting .log file to Sonarqube readable file

Tags: unit-testing, sonarqube

I have a .log file which gives the minimum information about the unit test case execution. The log contains, the date, pass, fail information, error message if any. I need to upload this to sonar qube and see the unit test case result. Just the unit test case result. that would be total number of test cases, the execution results. From this I need to get the unit test case coverage. How can I get a dash board in sonar qube with this .log file? Should I convert the .log file to XML file in Nunit format? Or do we have a simple format for sonarqube?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the [Generic Test Data](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Generic+Test+Data) format. Convert your log file into the XML format described in the docs, and use the `sonar.coverageReportPaths` property to specify the path to the file.

Comment: Hi Ann, I have created a sample XML in generic test data format. And executed the commands and the project is visible in sonar dashboard. Where should I check for the unit test case execution result in sonarqube?

Comment: I could not find the test case pass/fail information in the SonarQube UI.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the [Generic Test Data](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Generic+Test+Data) feature.